# Ellipses in center of string(string can be any language ie. Hindi, Tamil etc) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my text field i support input of various languages(English, Hindi, Tamil etc). I want to show ellipses in center of text when the string length is greater then the input field.
example: ellip...lipses

Comment: By greater do you mean it is big enough to overflow or just number of characters?

Comment: @Fma overflow of characters. When the string is in english then i am able to place the ellipses in correct position. But if it is in some other language(Hindi, Tamil etc) then i am facing problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width
Use the text width calculation answer to this question with on change. If text width is greater than your input field width show ellipses

Comment: @Fma Pls check the example: https://jsfiddle.net/Laz536x9/  when the string is in other language substring which i am using is giving the exact substring.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a working example

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table><tr><td> 
            <div id="x"></div> 
        </td></tr></table>
        <br/>
        <textarea id="t" onkeyup="foo(100)"></textarea>
        <br/>

        <script>
            function foo(maxSize){
                var x = document.getElementById("x");
                var t = document.getElementById("t");

                var tamil = /[\u0300-\u036f\u1dc0-\u1dff\u20d0-\u20ff\ufe20-\ufe2f\u0b82\u0b83\u0bbe\u0bbf\u0bc0-\u0bc2\u0bc6-\u0bc8\u0bca-\u0bcd\u0bd7]/g
                var hindi = /[\u901\u902\u903\u93c\u93e\u93f\u940\u941\u942\u943\u944\u945\u946\u947\u948\u949\u94a\u94b\u94c\u94d\u951\u952\u953\u954\u962\u963]/g
                var pos = 0;
                for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
                    pos++;
                    while(pos<t.value.length && (t.value.charAt(t.value.length-pos)+"").match(tamil)){
                        pos++;
                    }
                    while(pos<t.value.length && (t.value.charAt(t.value.length-pos)+"").match(hindi)){
                        pos++;
                    }
                }

                var y = t.value.substr(0,t.value.length-pos);
                var ending = t.value.substr(y.length,t.value.length);
                x.innerHTML = y + ending;

                while(x.offsetWidth>maxSize && y.length>1){
                    pos = 1;
                    while(pos<y.length-2 && (y.charAt(y.length-pos-1)+"").match(tamil)){
                        pos++;
                    }
                    while(pos<y.length-2 && (y.charAt(y.length-pos-1)+"").match(hindi)){
                        pos++;
                    }
                    y = y.substr(0,y.length-pos);
                    x.innerHTML = y + "..." + ending;
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Input text into textarea, result is displayed on the div. Tag table is for the div to be not as wide as the body.

Hindi combaining characters [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9524664/4366471)

Tamil combaining characters [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13820061/4366471)

Comment: If the text is in hindi or tamil language i am not getting the proper truncated text.